# Modules are not recognized on pytest after installing them

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I did the following:

- imported a pytest project
- create a virtual environment for that poject
- install the following modules: pdb, pytest, selenium
- set the virtualenv python as the interpreter

when typing 'import "module name" it shows

```
pytest : The term 'pytest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pytest
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pytest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

- Install these modules globally. Still the same error

Installed the modules and expected them to work